# PDF file including a black and white print version

Tags: pdftex, pdf

Is it possible **to include in a pdf with colours** (no images but some simple vector graphics created by `TikZ`) also information for a black an white print (or a print in general), ie. defining that a blue colored text showed be printed pitch black instead of the greyish graystyle of blue?

**Update:**

My aim is to have a single pdf (not *.tex) file that includes information that the colours should be printed black instead gray/blue if the person chooses to print the file but on the screen all colours should appear a intended.

Comment: You can simply set a boolean switch using `\newif`; e.g.: `\newif\ifcolour` and then `\ifcolour <put "colour" commands here> \else <black and white commands here> \fi`, then process with either `\colourtrue` or `\colourfalse` (which will be the default).  You can do it all from the command line similar to how I outlined in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71293/increasing-the-text-size-in-tufte-documents/71559#71559).

Comment: And there is also the [`ocg-p`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p?lang=en) package, and [`ocgtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgtools), [`ocgx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx)....

Comment: that's not what i'm looking for -- it has to be the same pdf file. my aim is to send a single pdf file to another person and if the person to print the pdf file all trhe blue colours should be printed pitch black instead of gray!

Comment: I see (maybe: did you try the OCG packages? [I haven't.]). So this now sounds more like a printer problem. Why aren't you simply instructing your printer to print in black and not grayscale (or RGB, or...)? This seems far easier than making the PDF "be" in two colours at the same time and which also somehow also communicates to the printer that only one of these two colours should be printed.  In fact, I believe this is the advice [Adobe gives](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-black-white-acrobat-reader.html).

Comment: Is there a way to use `hyperref` or an other package to pre-set the printing option of `acrobat` to b/w? I had a look at the `hyperref` documentation but it seems there is no option for the color.

Comment: `hyperref` has many options for colour, which is how I'd recommend using the `\newif` idea (e.g., with the `hidelinks` option), but I don't think it can set printer options -- which seems rather far outside the purpose of the package. Anyway, would an Adobe-specific answer be of much value? It wouldn't help me: I don't have it installed on my phone, tablet, or computer.

Comment: `hyperref` has some options to pre-set the pdf reader including `duplex`, `a4paper` and to pre-set the printing option to "do not scale" (and even more to change the appearers of the pdf reader like turn on/off menu bars etc ) unfortunately there is no option to pre-set the printer to b/w

Comment: Indeed. I think you are expecting quite a bit from `hyperref`, which isn't really about printing at all (and of course the default behaviour is supposed to produce the "link boxes", which are not supposed to be printed), and certainly not about whether  diagrams are in colour or not. I wish I could help, but I still think this is fairly easily solved from the command line....