# Alternative indents for fullwidth in tufte-latex

Tags: conditionals, tufte, parindent

I’m trying to add a larger indent to accomodate for the increased line width when using `fullwidth` in tufte-latex.

It’s not working, the same new indent is applied to all paragraphs.

Result with current code:

[image: Result with current code]

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

My mwe (not proficient in LaTeX — just an avid beginner):

`tufte-wideindent.sty`:

```
% Alternative indent for fullwidth
\def\@tufte@reset@par{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@fullwidth}}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{6.0pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{6.0pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{6pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}{}
}
\@tufte@reset@par
```

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

% Just some sample text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Custom indent for fullwidth
\usepackage{tufte-wideindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{fullwidth}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71293/increasing-the-text-size-in-tufte-documents/71559#72706) answer.

I’ve also uploaded a [mwe](https://www.overleaf.com/read/swnrstygzmkj) on overleaf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't just post a link to Overleaf but rather post your MWE as part of the question. Links may break (this one certainly will) and most people here prefer their own TeX installation to Overleaf. Also, you link does not really seem to be an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (stressing the _minimal_ part here). Please boil it down to just the necessary parts and then edit it into your question.

Comment: Thanks, I just did. Lack of understanding of LaTex conditionals doesn’t help either. Added this tag, hopefully that’s narrowing it down.