# Increase font size in running headers on tufte book style

Tags: tufte, header

I have used the solution on [Increasing the text size in tufte documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71293/increasing-the-text-size-in-tufte-documents/72706#72706)

to change the size of the main text of a tufte book, but the headers remain the same. How can I change that as well?

Example document:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,14pt]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{tufte-largeprint}

\title{Beer and frogs} \author[Ruth Lazkoz]{Ruth Lazkoz}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\mainmatter \chapter{Blaise Pascal}

\section{ inventor}

Soportamos un enorme peso sobre nuestras cabezas sin ser conscientes de ello
\newpage mas cosas

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. ! Please copy the code you used (but don't delete the link), it will be easier for us to help you. Asking people to fetch the code on another page may end in less people willing to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The headers are defined in `tufte-common.def` with `\fancyhead` commands starting on line 1457 (version *2015/06/21 v3.5.2 Common code for the Tufte-LaTeX styles*). You can redefine this to be printed in `\normalsize`, which the style file defines to be larger.

Edit: used the MWE from the OP. Because it uses `\mainmatter`, and `tufte-book.cls` sets the headers in that command, you need to redefine that. You can choose to put the redefinition in the `tufte-largeprint.sty` file or in the document itself. Here the modifications are shown in the document itself to make it self-contained. Note that in this case you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because there is an `@` symbol in the code (in `\boolean{@tufte@twoside}`).

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{tufte-largeprint}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \@mainmattertrue%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@twoside}}%
    {% two-side
      \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}%
      \fancyhead[LE]{\normalsize\thepage\quad\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\plaintitle}}}% book title
      \fancyhead[RO]{\normalsize\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\leftmark}}\quad\thepage}% chapter title
    }%
    {% one-side
      \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\normalsize\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\plaintitle}}\quad\thepage}% book title
    }%
}
\makeatother

\title{Beer and frogs} \author[Ruth Lazkoz]{Ruth Lazkoz}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\mainmatter
\chapter{Blaise Pascal}

\section{ inventor}

Soportamos un enorme peso sobre nuestras cabezas sin ser conscientes de ello
\newpage mas cosas

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am afraid it has not had any effect. I wonder if I have some clashing option somewhere.

Comment: @RuthLazkoz if this didn't work then you should provide a small example document with this code in it that does not work, then we can try to find what the problem is.

Comment: This is my file below

Comment: @RuthLazkoz you should edit it into your question and not post it as an answer - because it is not an answer to the question. But I'll take a look at it - the first difference is that this is `tufte-book` whereas the link you had in your question was about `tufte-handout`, so I guess that is the problem (and that is also why you always need to provide such a minimal file when you ask your questions, to avoid answerers to spend time on solutions that do not work for you).

Comment: @RuthLazkoz I edited my answer using your example code.

Comment: @RuthLazkoz another edit now using `\mainmatter` (I forgot I had commented that in my earlier edit, the previous redefinitions did not work when `\mainmatter` was called, but the current code works in that case).

Comment: This is not producing a `smallcaps` in the headers even though your code explicitly calls for it. How to make headers with `smallcaps`?

Comment: @Damitr as you can see from the screenshot in the answer (which was made using this code) the header is printed in smallcaps. If you don't get smallcaps then either your code is different from this, or possibly you have a different (maybe newer) version of the Tufte class for which this solution does not work. You can post a new question with a new MWE and your output (and a link to this question) if you think that it is a version problem.

Comment: If it was in `smallcaps` shouldn't "B" in Beer be larger than "EER"? Right now it is appearing to be of the same size, as in allcaps.

Comment: @Damitr Ah, I understand your comment now. In the Tufte class `\smallcaps` is defined as `\scshape \MakeTextLowercase {#1}`, so the input is first converted into lower case before applying small caps. If you want to keep the original upper case letters then you can use `\textsc` instead of `\smallcaps` in the code in this answer (in all three `\fancyhead` commands).

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[b5paper,14pt]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{tufte-largeprint}

\title{Beer and frogs}
\author[Ruth Lazkoz]{Ruth Lazkoz}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\mainmatter
\chapter{Blaise Pascal}

\section{ inventor}

Soportamos un enorme peso sobre nuestras cabezas sin ser conscientes de ello  
\newpage
mas cosas

\end{document}
```